# Spacing in flalign affected by mathpazo

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, align, mathpazo

I got the following (partly shorted) equation:

[image: align]

I would like to get rid of the space left of the equation (left of `Q'`) so that the label (0.2) fits on the right side.

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    12pt,
    parskip=half
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\op}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    Q'&(s,x) \nonumber\\
    &\mid s=(f,r)() \wedge x=\mathcal{E}(r) &&= [\mathcal{E}(f())]\\
    &\mid s=(f,r)(q_1,...,q_z) &&= \left[\mathcal{E}(f(p_1,...,p_z)) \middle\vert
            \begin{aligned}
              &x' = \op{split}(x,r(q_1,...,q_z)),\\
                &(x_1,...,x_z) \in x',\\
                &p_i \in Q'(q_i,x_i),1 \leq i \leq z
            \end{aligned}
            \right]
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Using `flalign`:

[image: flalign]

Using `flalign` and `\usepackage{mathpazo}`:

[image: flalign+mathpazo]

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    12pt,
    parskip=half,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\newcommand*{\op}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
Q'&(s,x) \nonumber\\
&\mid s=(f,r)() \wedge x=\mathcal{E}(r) &&= [\mathcal{E}(f())]\\
&\mid s=(f,r)(q_1,...,q_z) &&= \left[\mathcal{E}(f(p_1,...,p_z)) \middle\vert
        \begin{aligned}
          &x' = \op{split}(x,r(q_1,...,q_z)),\\
            &(x_1,...,x_z) \in x',\\
            &p_i \in Q'(q_i,x_i),1 \leq i \leq z
        \end{aligned}
        \right] \label{eq:q'_fr}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

While `flalign` solves the problem, `mathpazo` seems to distort the alignment in the middle of the equation. Why is that?

Comment: Using `flalign` environment should do what you desire.

Comment: Consider reading section **25 `align` environments** (p 43 onward) of Herbert's [`mathmode` document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf). It has a number of examples of use of `align` and friends environments.

Comment: Hmm, `flalign` really worked :) Thanks both of you!

Comment: You mention in a deleted comment "And I don't really want to get rid of the space left of the aligned `=`s." Why is that? To be blunt, "it don't look nice."

Comment: Because this should model the guard notation of programming languages like Haskell and the right `=` has a different meaning then the left. It's basically a case environment in reverse.

Comment: Should I delete the question? Otherwise, one of you has to answer this :)

Comment: I just tried it in my real document where I use `mathpazo` and it adds more space than without. Have a look at the screenshots. Do you have a quick idea for this? Otherwise I'll open a separate question.

Comment: @neo: `flalign` in the MWE you provided does *not* insert the addition space you mention in the update. How about updating your MWE with the appropriate use so that the result can be replicated by the community.

Comment: There you go. It's `mathpazo` causing the difference.

Comment: @neo: I've updated your question to now reflect (hopefully) the true problem - an interaction between `amsmath`'s `flalign` and `mathpazo`.

Comment: @Werner: As much as I like `Mathmode.pdf` as a *reference*, the fact that it doesn't outright scream "do not use `eqnarray`" means that I cannot in good faith recommend as anything else. Certainly not as a guide.

Comment: @kahen: True. Hence the reference to "a number of examples." A guide/reference will most certainly come from AMS (see [`amsldoc`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf)).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by trial and error like this:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    12pt,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{mleftright}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}

\newcommand*{\op}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
\mathmakebox[.5em][r]{Q'}
  &(s,x) \nonumber\\
  &{\mid}\; s=(f,r)() \wedge x=\mathcal{E}(r)
    &&= [\mathcal{E}(f())] 
  \\
  &{\mid}\; s=(f,r)(q_1,\dots,q_z)
    &&=
    \mleft[
      \mathcal{E}(f(p_1,\dots,p_z)) 
    \middle\vert
      \begin{aligned}
      &x' = \op{split}(x,r(q_1,\dots,q_z)),\\
      &(x_1,\dots,x_z) \in x',\\
      &p_i \in Q'(q_i,x_i),1 \leq i \leq z
      \end{aligned}
    \mright]
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

However, this will probably break badly when you either change fonts or page parameters. For instance, the normal page parameters you get without calling `geometry` will not pose unsurmountable problems, because the text width would be larger. On the contrary, with `mathpazo` the average width of the glyphs is bigger than Computer Modern's, so the trick won't work and the display simply won't fit.

Here's the example. In such tough cases some manual adjusting is almost always needed.

[image]

The very same code with `mathpazo`; if you look at the result you'll see that the material won't fit no matter how you push left the first "Q".

[image]

Again, the same code (but with simply `Q'` instead of `\mathmakebox[.5em][r]{Q'}`, without leaving control to `geometry`:

[image]

---

Just to show how page parameters can influence the final result, here's what I get without leaving control to `geometry` with your original input:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, to be honest, it's not really satisfying to do stuff like that... I mean, in my eyes, the real problem is: Why isn't `align` clever enough to make the middle space before the equal signs smaller so that everything fits?